# Javascript issue in IE9 with Windows 7 Professional and not in Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: javascript, windows-7, internet-explorer-9

1. Is it possible to get a javascript related error only in IE9 with Windows 7 Professional and not in IE9 with Windows Enterprise?
2. Can there be any difference in the way IE9 behaves with respect to javascript between a 32-bit Windows 7 and a 64-bit Windows 7?

Please help me with this.  The full javascript function is below.

```
function foo() {
    var isChecked = false;
    var checkBoxField = "MyCheckBox1";
    for(j=0;j<document.forms[0].elements.length;j++) {
        if(document.forms[0].elements[j].name.search(checkBoxField) == 0) {
            if (document.forms[0].elements[j].checked == true) { 
                isChecked = true;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(isChecked);
}
```

The isChecked variable has to be true when the checkBoxField is checked.  It is **true in IE9-Windows 7 Enterprise Edition** (Not sure about 32-bit or 64-bit) and it is **false in IE9-Windows 7 Professional Edition** (32-bit)

Apologies.  After looking at the IE settings in the exact machine where the issue occurs, it is clear that it is due to caching.  The setting **Preserve Favorites website data** preserves the old js file and is not downloading the updated version (even if we try to clear cookies, history, temporary files etc).  Once that setting is unchecked - history, cache cleared everything started working.
Cheers,

Comment: What is the error and what line of code (plus a little context) is causing it?  The question, as asked, can be answered by saying "yes" and "yes".  Or "no" and "no".  Neither answer will help you or future visitors.

Comment: You mean IE9 with Windows 7 Get and IE9 with Other OS Not Getting ?

Comment: Thanks.  Sure I will post the code. @Sudantha - Yes IE9 with Windows 7 Professional works.  IE9 with Windows 7 Enterprise not works

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Once I do have an error in IE8 Win2K/WinXP only. IE alerted "Stack overflow at line 0".

Comment: But why would it be possible? Barring a bug in a given revision of IE (are they definitely identical versions?) or maybe a 64-bit-specific bug (are you using 32-bit IE on both machines, or 64-bit on the 64-bit one?), or a bug in a plug-in (are they identical too?)

Comment: I have tested it in IE9-Windows 7 Professional 64-bit OS.  It works as expected.  Then my client must be using a 32-bit and its not working.  I am confused.  Please have a look at the javascript code.  Is there a possibility that it is due to any kind of IE security or javascript settings?

Comment: Your code isn't usable or debugable like that. What is `j`? What is `checkBoxField`? How does the HTML look like? When/how is the code called?

Comment: function foo() {
    var isChecked = false; 
    var checkBoxField = "MyCheckBox1";
    for(j=0;j<document.forms[0].elements.length;j++){
    if(document.forms[0].elements[j].name.search(checkBoxField) == 0){ 
    if (document.forms[0].elements[j].checked == true) { 
    isChecked = true; 
    }  
    }
    }
    alert(isChecked);
    }  This is the entire code.  A checkbox named **MyCheckBox1** is available in the page.

Comment: I don't understand this statement : if(document.forms[0].elements[j].name.search(checkBoxField) == 0) ... the operator should be !=, should not be ?

Comment: No.  The `search()` function returns `0` when `checkBoxField` is available in the form.  If it is available it goes to the next `if` statement to confirm whether it is `checked` or `unchecked`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies. After looking at the IE settings in the exact machine where the issue occurs, it is clear that it is due to caching. The setting Preserve Favorites website data preserves the old js file and is not downloading the updated version (even if we try to clear cookies, history, temporary files etc). Once that setting is unchecked - history, cache cleared everything started working

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difference in different windows version, since most time you'll be using 32 bit ie. But you never know what kinda of bug is in ie javascript

what you can try is is use [jquery](http://jquery.com/)
you code looks like

```
function foo() {
    var isChecked = $("name='MyCheckBox1':first").attr('checked');      
    alert(isChecked);
}
```

set your checkbox id to MyCheckBox1 and it further simplifies

```
function foo() {
    var isChecked = $("#MyCheckBox1").attr('checked');      
    alert(isChecked);
}
```

Not sure if it'll help you, but that's my 20 cent.